# Template function that returns object with random values

Tags: c++, templates, random

I would like to have a template function that returns an object of whatever class with random values. I tried the function below but it doesn't work, because `tab` is read as a `uint32_t*` rather than a sequence of `numberOfCalls` values of type `uint32_t`.

```cpp
std::random_device rd;

template <typename Type>
Type RandomObject(void)
{
    constexpr auto numberOfCalls = (sizeof(Type) + sizeof(uint32_t) - 1u)/sizeof(uint32_t);
    uin32_t tab[numberOfCalls];

    for (auto i = 0u; i < numberOfCalls; ++i)
        tab[i] = rd();

    return reinterpret_cast<Type>(tab);
}
```

Here's an example of something I would like to do.

```cpp
struct Test
{
    uint64_t s;
    uint64_t t;
    uint32_t x;
    uint32_t y;
    uint32_t z;
};

int32_t main(void)
{
    const auto foo = ::RandomObject<Test>();
    // do things
    return 0;
}
```

Of course I could simply implement `RandomObject<Test>` but I'd much prefer having one robust template function that works for everything.

Comment: There are simpler ways of achieving the same goal. Especially since this will only work for structs of integral types.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is not to cast between arbitrary types. The set of allowed casts is rather narrow (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast))

Comment: "works for everything" ? This approach will fail for `std::string` or anything that uses pointers.

Comment: There is no way to generate random valid values of an arbitrary type.

Comment: i would rather write a template that returns a tuple of random values of arbitrary types and from there is is only a small step to use that tuple to invoke any types constructor

Comment: You could cast the pointer to type instance to a `char*` and fill `sizeof(type)` `char`s with random byte values (to form something like a variation of [std::memset()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset)). However, this will work at best for plain old data but not for complex classes (as already mentioned).

Comment: Thank you @Scheff I hadn't thought of that! I'm going to try that. I agree with the above comments, anything with pointers won't work, but I didn't have these things in mind when I said "everything".

Comment: in my mind `std::vector` and `std:.string` is 99% of everything :P You might be interested in `std::is_trivially_copyable` which can tell you if a type will be fine with memsetting its memory